# Messed up Python path in OS X

Tags: macos, python, path

I am using python 2.7 in Mac OS X (10.7).

I have been trying to install OpenCV, but to no avail. In one attempt to get OpenCV to install properly I tried the MacPorts version of OpenCV, and I switched the python link to the MacPorts version using the command `sudo port select --set python`. However, I really would like to keep the `python` command to link to `/usr/bin/python` instead of its current link of `/opt/local/bin/python`.

By the way, why are the commands shown below output different results?

```
Unknown:~ jake$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
Unknown:~ jake$ whereis python
```

---

**EDIT**

> doesn't port select give you some other options?

Thank you for the suggestion.

Latest attempt:

```
$ port select python
Available versions for python:
    none
    python25-apple
    python26-apple
    python27 (active)
    python27-apple
$ port select python27-apple
Warning: Unable to get active selected version: The specified group 'python27-apple' does not exist.
Error: The 'list' command failed: The specified group 'python27-apple' does not exist.
```

I wasn't using the apple version (I believe apple only provided 2.6). However, I got the python that I was previously using from [python.org](http://python.org/). So, I am not sure what command with `port select python` I am supposed to use to switch to that version.

Thank you `slhck` for you help and suggestions.

Comment: Because `whereis` and `which` use different paths for searching. Check `man whereis` and `man which` respectively.

Comment: Regarding your problem: Can't you just switch it back? What specifically fails when installing OpenCV? Can you include error messages, logs, etc?

Comment: AFAIK both the Xcode and MacPorts methods for installing give you no other option than '/opt/local/bin/' for the opencv_xxxx utilities as this is necessary to conform to MacPorts conventions. I could be wrong.

Comment: @slhck "Can't you just switch it back?" What is the command for that. As for OpenCV errors, I wanted to keep working on that for a while to before I post questions about it. I just needed to fix my python path in the mean time since I have more important projects I need to work on that rely on the old packages. But thanks for the support, I might post that as another question soon enough.

Comment: I have never worked with MacPorts, so I'm not entirely sure how exactly the command works, but doesn't `port select` give you some other options? Or `port select list python`?